# How to sort columns of datetype data and get the column name as array in new column while ignoring Nulls in pyspark?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

The data looks like below and i want an additional column named 'result_column'

| person_id | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | result_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 2022-01-23 | 2022-01-22 | Null | 2022-01-25 | [d2,d1,d4] |
| p2 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-16 | Null | Null | [d1,d2] |

Sorry if my question framing is not comprehensible but i hope, the data above conveys what i need. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark SQL:

```
  transform(
      array_except(sort_array(
       zip_with(array(d1,d2,d3,d4), array('d1','d2','d3','d4'), (x,y) -> case when x is not null then concat_ws(x,y) end)
       ), array(null))
  , x -> right(x, 2)
  )
```

My approach was to zip the column name and date together, dropping nulls, concat them with date first, sort it, strip out the date.

There may be a more elegant solution but it looks like it works